# How to hide a template in a certain page

Tags: html, meteor

I want to hide the Footer on my in my 'Landing_Page.html' page. The landing page's template name is "Landing_Page". My page format is shown in this file:

app-body.html

```
{{> Header}}
{{>Template.dynamic template=main}}
{{> Footer}}
```

I've looked online but have only found ways to do this through php but not on html. I would appreciate any help on how to achieve this.

Comment: What do you mean? Can you hide it just through stylings? Why do you want to hide it? If you don't want it to be there why not just remove the template?

Comment: Its just because I don't want to have the footer on that particular page, but I still want it for my other web pages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using `iron-router`, you can get the name of the current template that has been served using :

```
var routeName = Router.current().route.getName();
```

So you can have a helper in **main-body.js** like:

```
isLandingPage: function(){
    var routeName = Router.current().route.getName();
    if (routerName === 'landingPageTemplateNameHere')
       return false;
    else 
       return true;
}
```

Now you can make use of handlebars to show / hide the footer in your landing page like so:

```
{{> Header}}
{{>Template.dynamic template=main}}
{{#if isLandingPage}}
    {{> Footer}}
{{/if}}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you sir